# standard normal distribution with slutsky

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, estimation

i have a small question. We Have $S_{n}$ with $ S_{n}\overset{D}{\longrightarrow}N(0,\sigma^{2})$ (normal distribution). We have also an estimator for $\sigma$, it is $\hat\sigma$. Than we $\hat\sigma^{2}\overset{P}{\longrightarrow}\sigma^{2}$. So my question is: why its follows with Slutksy : $$ \dfrac{S_{n}}{\hat{\sigma^{2}}}\longrightarrow N(0,1)$$

It would be very helpfull, when someone has some tips!

Thank you, greets, Hendrik.

Comment: Since the conditions of Slutsky are satisfied :-), namely that $\sigma$ is not random element and the corresponding convergence for $\hat{\sigma}$ is in p-mode. Take a look also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem

Comment: but slutsky says:   $ \dfrac{S_{n}}{\hat{\sigma}}\rightarrow \dfrac{N(0,\sigma^{2})}{\sigma^{2}}$. Why it is   $ N(0,1)$

Comment: the deonominator of the limit in your comment shall be $\sigma$.

Comment: $ \dfrac{S_{n}}{\hat{\sigma^{2}}}\rightarrow \dfrac{N(0,\sigma^{2})}{\sigma^{2}}$. But why it is   $ N(0,1)$? I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S_n{\stackrel d\to} N(0,\sigma^2)$ is an abbreviation for $S_n{\stackrel d\to} Z$ where $Z\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. This might seem pedantic, and in fact ordinarily I wouldn't bother with this point, but you seem to be confused about what $\alpha\cdot N(0,\sigma^2)$ means if $\alpha$ is a constant. Slutsky's theorem tells us that, since $\hat\sigma_n{\stackrel p\to}\sigma$ in probability, $\frac{S_n}{\hat\sigma_n}{\stackrel d\to}\frac{Z}{\sigma}$. If $Z\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, what is the distribution of $\frac{Z}{\sigma}$?

As a minor point, you should not be looking at $\frac{S_n}{\hat\sigma_n^2}$ (remove the square).

Comment: exact this is my question. Sorry but i dont now how can $\frac{1}{\sigma}$ make $N(0,\sigma^2)$ to $N(0,1)$ (really sorry for bad english)

Comment: Do the calculation. If $Z\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, then $P(\frac{Z}{\sigma}\le x)=P(Z\le \sigma x)=\ldots$. Use the density of a normal distribution and appropriate integral substitutions. To be honest, this is probably something you should know by the time you encounter Slutsky's theorem.

Comment: Jop thanks! i was very confused, somethimes forget the eazies things

Answer (score 0):

We will apply the following case of [Slutsky's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem):
Let $\{X_n\}$, $\{Y_n\}$ be sequences of random elements. 
If $X_n$ converges in distribution to a random element $X$ (as $n \rightarrow \infty$) and $Y_n$ converges in probability to a constant $c$ then $X_n Y_n$ converges in distribution to $cX$.

Your assumptions can be stated as

1. ${S_n}/{\sigma}$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
2. ${\sigma}/{\hat{\sigma}}$ converges in probability to the number $c = 1$.

Write
$$
  \frac{S_n}{\hat{\sigma}} = \frac{S_n}{\sigma} \cdot \frac{\sigma}{\hat{\sigma}}
$$
Then the result follows immediately from putting $X_n = S_n / \sigma$, $Y_n = \sigma / \hat{\sigma}$.